# Positive integer N as the sum of positive integers using stack

Tags: c++, pointers, integer, sum, stack

So, I am working on this project, where we have to write a positive integer number n as the of positive integers. And all solutions should be ordered, for instance:

```
n = 3
1: 1 1 1 
2: 1 2
3: 3

n = 5 
1: 1 1 1 1 1 
2: 1 1 1 2 
3: 1 1 3 
4: 1 2 2  
5: 2 3 
7: 5
```

I got (I think) very good algorithm on paper; yet, I have a trouble putting it into the code. The first time it gets into the inner do-while loop it runs smoothly, but then 'top' doesn't get a right value from the getTop function.
Here is my Stack.h file

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    template <class T>
    class Stack
    {
    private:
        // Structure for the stach nodes
        struct StackNode
        {
            T value;          // Value in the node
            StackNode *next;  // Pointer to next node
        };

        StackNode *top;     // Pointer to the stack top
        int count;

    public:
        //Constructor
        Stack(){top = NULL; count = 0;}

        // Destructor
        ~Stack();

        // Stack operations
        bool push(T);
        bool pop(T &);
        bool isEmpty();
        int getCount();
        int getTop();
        void print();

    };


template <class T>
Stack<T>::~Stack()
{
    StackNode *currNode, *nextNode;

    // Position nodePtr at the top of the stack.
    currNode = top;

    // Traverse the list deleting each node.
    while (currNode) //while (currNode != NULL)
    {
        nextNode = currNode->next;
        delete currNode;
        currNode = nextNode;
    }
}


template <class T>
bool Stack<T>::push(T item)
{
    StackNode *newNode; // Pointer to a new node

    // Allocate a new node and store num there.
    newNode = new StackNode;
    if (!newNode)
        return false;
    newNode->value = item;

    // Update links and counter
    newNode->next = top;
    top = newNode;
    count++;

    return true;
}


template <class T>
bool Stack<T>::pop(T &item)
{
    StackNode *temp; // Temporary pointer

    // empty stack
    if (count == 0)
        return false;

    // pop value off top of stack
    item = top->value;
    temp = top->next;
    delete top;
    top = temp;
    count--;

    return true;
}

template <class T>
bool Stack<T>::isEmpty()
{
    return count == 0;
}


template <class T>
int Stack<T>::getCount()
{
    return count;
}


template <class T>
int Stack<T>::getTop() 
{
    if (this->top->next == NULL)
    {
        cout << "EXCEPTION" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        return this->top->next->value;
    }
    //return top->value;
}

template <class T>
void Stack<T>::print()
{
    StackNode *newNode;
    newNode = top;
    for (int i = count; i > 0; i--)
    {
    cout << newNode -> value;
    cout << " ";
    newNode = newNode -> next;      
    }

}

#endif
```

and here is my main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Stack.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int input = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    int pop1 = 0;
    int pop2 = 0;
    int top;
    int CurrSum = 0;
    Stack<int> *stack = new Stack<int>;
    Stack<int> *tmpStack = new Stack<int>;

    cout << "Please enter a integer: " << endl;
    cin  >> input;
    while(input < 0)
    {
        cout << "Please enter a POSITIVE integer: " << endl;
        cin  >> input;
    }

    if ( input != 0)
    {
        counter ++;
        for (int n = 1; n <= input; n ++)
        {
            stack -> push(1);
        }

     do
     {


        do
        {
            top = stack->getTop();
            pop1 = stack->pop(top);
            top = stack->getTop();
            pop2 = stack->pop(top);

            //increment the pop2 and push it back
            stack->push(pop2 + 1);

            top = stack->getTop();

            CurrSum = CurrSum - pop1 - pop2 + top;

            if (CurrSum < input)
            {
                stack->push(top);
                CurrSum = CurrSum + top;
            }
            else if (CurrSum > input)
            {
                pop1 = stack->pop(top);
                top = stack->getTop();
                pop2 = stack->pop(top);

                CurrSum = CurrSum - pop1 - pop2 + top;
            }

        }while (CurrSum == input);

        cout << counter << ": ";
        stack->print();
        top = stack->getTop();

     }while (top != input);

        system("pause");
    }
    else
        cout << "Thank you for using this program. Bye!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: _`stack -> push(1);`_ Did you mean to write `stack -> push(n);` here?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Ithink he wrote what he meant to write but he forgot to set the `CurrSum` to `n` right after that `for` loop. However I must admit I sill didn't fully understand that algorithm...

Comment: `Stack<T>::top()` returns the element after top, fixing this crashes your code which seems flawed. Here is some output: [4]: 2, 1, 1, 1, 
[3]: 2, 1, 1, 
[2]: 2, 1, 
[1]: 2,

Comment: I don't understand your example with n=5. I thought the idea was to always sum the last 2 elements, but then you are going from `3: 1 1 3` to `4: 1 2 2` which I don't understand. What is the rule exactly?

Comment: @alexlop i did forgot to set CurrSum to n after the loop, thanks

Comment: @fabioturati what it should do is print out all possibilities of how you can write the number N. so, so, you can write n = 5 as `1 1 3` and `1 2 2'. both of their sum will give 5.

Comment: @alex so, let's say we have number 5. what i do is i write 1's into the stack - in this case it's five. then i pop last two integers and push the second popped item backed adding 1 to it. i update my `CurrSum` and compare it to the input. if it's less I push top again to the stack. if that's a sequence i need it will be printed, if it's not, it will quit the loop, but will run until the stack has only one number. based on scratch paper, it works. sorry if you have trouble with my explanation, i would better explain it on paper

Comment: To be honest I didn't try to follow and debug the code. I just didn't have time for it. But from looking into the parts of it looks like `pop1` and `pop2` will always get values 0 or 1 because `Stack::pop` returns `bool`.

Comment: ... by the way, your example with 5 misses `6: 1 4`

Comment: @alex i changed pop from bool to int and modified it a bit and it works, actually. i think there is one thing in my algorithm. the case it misess is `2 3` for n = 5. it gets `1 4`. thanks for help

Answer (score -1):

First, you do not need to write that `Stack` class for yourself, it's already done for you: it's called [`std::stack`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack), and does exactly what you need. Second, you really don't need to dynamically allocate it, whether you use your own `Stack` or `std::stack`, though it does the same functionally, it is less efficient to allocate dynamically.

If that still doesn't work, you can now be sure that your algorithm is wrong (I didn't check it). Since it is a typical recursive problem, I'd try writing it recursively (now you don't need a Stack class at all), since recursive algorithms like this are usually easier to understand when you write them recursively. Later you can rewrite it iteratively if you want, once you understand what went wrong.

Comment: i know about this stl library, but I kind of still want to get my way through with my own set up of those functions

Comment: It cannot be considered as answer as it doesn't answer/solve the given issue. It should have been a comment.

Comment: @AlexLop. It is too long for a comment, isn't it?

Comment: @petersohn A too long comment is still not an answer, and can be split down into 2 ... so I recommend you move this to a comment